# Ionic2: Send Submit form data to service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic2, I want to send data from Form to web service using POST request, but every time I print the form data I found it empty and the service send me that it not received data.
this is my html code:

```
    <div class="login-box">
    <form #registerForm="ngForm">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col id="imageContainer">
                <button (click)="upload()" ion-button>Take Pic & Upload </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-list inset>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>{{ 'USERNAME' | translate }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="text" name="username" #username required></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>{{ 'MOBILENUMBER' | translate }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="text" name="mobile" #mobile required></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>{{ 'EMAILADDRESS' | translate }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="email" name="email" #email required></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="password" name="password" #password required></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>{{ 'CONFIRMPASSWORD' | translate }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="password" name="confirmpass" #confirmPass required></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                </ion-list>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="signup-col">
                <button ion-button class="submit-btn" (click)="signUp(username.value,email.value,password.value,mobile.value,confirmPass.value)" full type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid">sign up</button>
                <button ion-button class="register-btn" block clear (click)="login()">sign in</button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

    </form>
</div>
```

the service method:

```
register(username,email,password,mobile,) {

    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('user_name',username);
    body.append('email',email);
    body.append('mobile',mobile);
    body.append('password',password);
    body.append('image','dsdsdsddsd');

    console.log('body from service: ',body);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type","application/formdata");

    return this.http.post(this.registerUrl,body,{headers:headers})
    .map((response:Response)=>response.json())


}
```

the JS:

```
signUp(username,email,password,mobile,confirmPass) {

this.userService.register(username,email,password,mobile)
.subscribe(data=>{
    console.log('register data from service: ',data);
  },
  (err)=> console.log('error: ',err)
)
}
```

this is the received data from service: 
Object {Result: Array(0), Status: Object}
Result
:
Array(0)
Status
:
Object
message
:
Array(4)
0
:
"The user name field is required."
1
:
"The email field is required."
2
:
"The mobile field is required."
3
:
"The password field is required."
length
:
4

Comment: @AJT_82 there is no elements in body so it doesn't print any data and this is the problem not to print the data

Comment: Ah sorry, thanks for pointing out my mistake :) Hmm, have you tried `URLSearchParams` ? That's what I have used :) https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams

Comment: @AJT_82 thank's for your help i read about it and use these lines: paramsMap:Map<string,string> paramsMap.set('user_name','shimaa');then i have this error cannot read property of undefined

Comment: I usually use `let body = new URLSearchParams(); body.set('user_name': username)` and so on...

Comment: @AJT_82 yes thank's alot

Answer (score 1):

You have to stringify your data  before you send request use this function like this

```
let body =  JSON.stringify(body)  return this.http.post(this.registerUrl,body,{headers:headers})
    .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
```

Comment: the same problem